# How can I remove icons like "home" or "boot" from desktop

Tags: icons, root, home-directory

[ScreenShoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAfuz.jpg) I changed Ubuntu's languaje from Spanish to English, so folders like "Escritorio" are now "Desktop", and a lot of icons appeared in the Deskotop like "boot", "home", "otp", "root" etc.
How can I remove them? Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: Right click on them and delete them...before that pls post a screen shot if u can...

Comment: root boot home and the other folders are important i belive,  I just do not want to show them on the desktop, not delete them.

Comment: Deleting the icon on the desktop for root, boot, or home will not delete the actual folder, just the shortcut.

Comment: Do you have any `tweak tool` installed?

Comment: Yes, Unity Tweak Tool.

Comment: The icons I want to remove from the desktop have a padlock on them

Comment: They appeared after you switch language right? Run `sudo chown -R $USERNAME.$USERNAME file`

Comment: @George , I get `chown: cannot access 'file': No such file or directory`

Comment: Solve it using `sudo chown -R $USERNAME.$USERNAME file` 
and then `sudo rm  -f -r file` . Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped, cheers :)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files on the `Desktop` are mainly *links* to the actual locations of these files so removing them won't delete them from those locations. In your case some of these files were created when you switched language by a *root* process, so their *ownership* would be those of *root*.

To get rid of them:

1. Change ownership of these files with:

   ```
   sudo chown -R $USERNAME.$USERNAME  file
   ```
2. Then remove them as usual:

   ```
   rm -rf file
   ```